# Query returning repeated values on JSON clob

Tags: sql, json, spring, oracle, plsql

## Context:

I have this table, populated with thousands of entries:

```
CREATE TABLE PRICING_TAXAS.FATURAMENTOS_MCC
(
    ID_FATURAMENTO_MCC NUMBER(20) not null,
    ID_MCC NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    FATURAMENTO_INI NUMBER(18,2),
    FATURAMENTO_FINAL NUMBER(18,2),
    CONSTRAINT faturamento_mcc_pk primary key (ID_FATURAMENTO_MCC)
);
```

'FATURAMENTO_INI' and 'FATURAMENTO_FINAL' are currency values, representing a start value and an end value respectively.

Each 'ID_MCC' pairs with different ranges of start and end currency values, and each of these pairs are assigned to the pk 'ID_FATURAMENTO_MCC'.

Then, I have this query received from a spring service:

```
select  
    ftmcc.id_mcc as idMcc, 
    ( 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG 
        ( 
            JSON_OBJECT 
            ( 
                'idFaturamentoMcc' VALUE ftmcc.id_faturamento_mcc, 
                'faturamentoInicial' VALUE ftmcc.faturamento_ini, 
                'faturamentoFinal' VALUE ftmcc.faturamento_final 
            ) RETURNING CLOB 
        ) 
    ) as faturamentos 
from  
    FATURAMENTOS_MCC ftmcc 
join  
    MCC mcc 
on  
    mcc.mcc_cod in :#{#searchDTO.mccCodes} 
join  
    GRUPOMCC_ITEM gMccItem 
on  
    gMccItem.id_mcc = mcc.id_mcc 
where 
    ( 
        COALESCE(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome}, NULL) IS NULL 
        OR 
        ( 
            ftmcc.faturamento_ini <= TO_NUMBER(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome}) 
            AND 
            ftmcc.faturamento_final >= TO_NUMBER(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome}) 
        ) 
    ) 
group by ftmcc.id_mcc
```

'MCC' is a table that receives the parameter 'mccCodes' and returnings an id.
This id is then paired as a foreign key (n to n) to the table 'GRUPOMCC_ITEM', returning a list of ids.
This list of ids are the 'id_mcc' column searched on the table 'FATURAMENTOS_MCC'.
The 'FATURAMENTOS_MCC' table is also filtered by the parameter 'monthlyGrossIncome' to restrain the currency ranges to those that fit the currency informed.

So, considering each 'id_mcc' on 'FATURAMENTOS_MCC' can have many combinations of currency ranges, but each combination is unique, the service should return only 1 combination per id_mdd.

But for some reason, its returning this:

```
[
    {
        "idMcc": 44565,
        "faturamentos": [
            {
                "idFaturamentoMcc": 2827,
                "faturamentoInicial": 5000,
                "faturamentoFinal": 19999
            },
            {
                "idFaturamentoMcc": 2827,
                "faturamentoInicial": 5000,
                "faturamentoFinal": 19999
            },
            {
                "idFaturamentoMcc": 2827,
                "faturamentoInicial": 5000,
                "faturamentoFinal": 19999
            },
            {
                "idFaturamentoMcc": 2827,
                "faturamentoInicial": 5000,
                "faturamentoFinal": 19999
            },
```

The 'idMcc' are not being repeated, which is fine, but the currency ranges are being duplicated.

Any luck?

I tried using DISTINCT on the JSON builder but didnt manage to make it work.

Comment: Is your first join missing `and mcc.id_mcc = ft cc.id_mcc`? If not then a [mre] with the other tables and data, and which doesn't rely on placeholder replacement (whatever the # values are) might be helpful. (Also the `in` will only work with a single bind value; the `coalesce` isn't doing anything; and `to_number` may not  be needed if you're binding data types properly.)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this duplication, you can use a subquery to first aggregate the currency ranges for each idMcc and then join this subquery with the MCC and GRUPOMCC_ITEM tables. Here's an example of how you can modify your query:

```
SELECT
    mcc.id_mcc AS idMcc,
    (
        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'idFaturamentoMcc' VALUE ftmcc.id_faturamento_mcc,
                'faturamentoInicial' VALUE ftmcc.faturamento_ini,
                'faturamentoFinal' VALUE ftmcc.faturamento_final
            ) RETURNING CLOB
        )
        FROM FATURAMENTOS_MCC ftmcc
        WHERE ftmcc.id_mcc = mcc.id_mcc
        AND (
            COALESCE(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome}, NULL) IS NULL
            OR (
                ftmcc.faturamento_ini <= TO_NUMBER(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome})
                AND
                ftmcc.faturamento_final >= TO_NUMBER(:#{#searchDTO.monthlyGrossIncome})
            )
        )
    ) AS faturamentos
FROM MCC mcc
JOIN GRUPOMCC_ITEM gMccItem ON gMccItem.id_mcc = mcc.id_mcc
WHERE mcc.mcc_cod IN :#{#searchDTO.mccCodes}
GROUP BY mcc.id_mcc;
```

This should prevent the duplication of currency ranges in your JSON result, as each idMcc will only be associated with its unique set of currency ranges.